# Recursion in Python 3.2

Tags: python, list, recursion, python-3.x

I am trying to wrap my head around recursion and have posted a working algorithm to produce all the subsets of a given list.

```
def genSubsets(L):
    res = []
    if len(L) == 0:
        return [[]]
    smaller = genSubsets(L[:-1])
    extra = L[-1:]
    new = []
    for i in smaller:
        new.append(i+extra)
    return smaller + new
```

Let's say my list is L = [0,1], correct output is [[],[0],[1],[0,1]]

Using print statements I have narrowed down that genSubsets is called twice before I ever get to the for loop. That much I get.

But why does the first for loop initiate a value of L as just [0] and the second for loop use [0,1]? How exactly do the recursive calls work that incorporate the for loop?

Comment: You can use [this](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html) for finding the flow of the code.

Comment: thanks Sibi! Thats awesome!

Answer (score 7):

I think this would actually be easier to visualize with a longer source list. If you use `[0, 1, 2]`, you'll see that the recursive calls repeatedly cut off the last item from the list. That is, recusion builds up a stack of recursive calls like this:

```
genSubsets([0,1,2])
    genSubsets([0,1])
        genSubsets([0])
            genSubsets([])
```

At this point it hits the "base case" of the recursive algorithm. For this function, the base case is when the list given as a parameter is empty. Hitting the base case means it returns an list containing an empty list `[[]]`. Here's how the stack looks when it returns:

```
genSubsets([0,1,2])
    genSubsets([0,1])
        genSubsets([0]) <- gets [[]] returned to it
```

So that return value gets back to the previous level, where it is saved in the `smaller` variable. The variable `extra` gets assigned to be a slice including only the last item of the list, which in this case is the whole contents, `[0]`.

Now, the loop iterates over the values in `smaller`, and adds their concatenation with `extra` to `new`. Since there's just one value in `smaller` (the empty list), `new` ends up with just one value too, `[]+[0]` which is `[0]`. I assume this is the value you're printing out at some point.

Then the last statement returns the concatenation of `smaller` and `new`, so the return value is `[[],[0]]`. Another view of the stack:

```
genSubsets([0,1,2])
    genSubsets([0,1]) <- gets [[],[0]] returned to it
```

The return value gets assigned to `smaller` again, `extra` is `[1]`, and the loop happens again. This time, `new` gets two values, `[1]` and `[0,1]`. They get concatenated onto the end of `smaller` again, and the return value is `[[],[0],[1],[0,1]]`. The last stack view:

```
genSubsets([0,1,2]) <- gets [[],[0],[1],[0,1]] returned to it
```

The same thing happens again, this time adding `2`s onto the end of each of the items found so far. `new` ends up as `[[2],[0,2],[1,2],[0,1,2]]`.

The final return value is `[[],[0],[1],[0,1],[2],[0,2],[1,2],[0,1,2]]`

Answer (score 3):

I am no big fan of trying to visualize the entire call graph for recursive function to understand what they do.

I believe there is a much *simpler* way:

**Enter fairy tale land** where recursive functions do *the right thing*™.

Just assume that `genSubsets(L)` works:

```
# This computes the powerset of the list L minus the last element
smaller = genSubsets(L[:-1])
```

Because this magically worked, the only entries that are missing are those, that contain the last element.

This fragment constructs all those missing subsets:

```
new = []
for i in smaller:
    new.append(i+extra)
```

Now we have those subsets containing the last element in `new` and we have those subsets *not* containing the last element in `smaller`.

It follows that we must now have all subsets, so we can return `new + smaller`.

The only thing left is the **base case** to make sure the recursion stops. Because the empty set (or list in this case) is an element of every power set, we can use that to stop the recursion: Requesting the powerset of an empty set is a set containing the empty set. So our base case is correct. Since every recursive step removes one element off the list, the base case *must* be encountered at some time.

Thus, the code really does produce the power set.

*Note*: The principle behind this is that of induction. If something works for some known *n<sub>0</sub>*, and we can prove that: The algorithm working for `n` implies it works for `n+1`, it must thus work for all *n ≥ n<sub>0</sub>*.